# Rails form helpers with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using rails 3.2.3 with devise to sign up and sign in users.
The problem is that devise (I might be wrong here) somehow overrider the interpretation of form helpers where an error in the form occures (for example, the registrations/new form). It puts the labels and the inputs, wich are wrong in some kind of div blocks and ruines the view.

How can I customize that behavior?

**UPDATE 1**

The views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb looks like this: https://gist.github.com/2585197

And here is the output if errors occur: https://gist.github.com/2585208

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate views for the model. For example

```
rails generate devise:views users
```

This gives you control over the views you get from devise.  Check out the documentation here

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I have done that and changed the views to fit the layout, but they still keep changing when form errors occur.

Comment: what are your form errors? Also try to restart your app when you make changes.

Comment: email taken, username taken. I did restart many times since Ihave made those changes, it was about couple weeks ago.

Comment: Why not remove   <%= f.error_notification %> in the form and use your universal ones,  i haven't tried it yet.  Or you can style those divs with the same css